# Running average over last x months

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to get a running average across a very simple table but the average relies on various grouped columns.  Whatever I try the average comes out the same as the current value.  It only "works" when I take out all the relevant columns apart from 1 in my table.  As soon as I add them back in and change the summary to "don't summarise" it breaks again.

My Table essentially has 4 columns.  CompanyNo, number of payments, month, year.  All i want to do is have an average for the current month and the previous 2 months for that companyNo only.

Example data

```
CompanyNo, Payments, TaxMonth, TaxYear  
1,100,1,2018  
1,200,2,2018  
1,300,3,2018  
2,100,1,2018  
2,500,2,2018  
2,1000,3,2018
```

I've also added a computed column called "FullDate" to try and help me out without any joy

```
FullDate = DATE(SQL_MonthlyData[TaxYear], SQL_MonthlyData[TaxMonth], 1)
```

I am simply trying to output the data in a table for now.

This is what i have currently for my 3 month average.

```
3MonthAverage = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('SQL_MonthlyData'[Payments]),
            DATEADD('SQL_MonthlyData'[FullDate].[Date], -3, MONTH)
        )
```

Two issues with it.  Firstly when i have companyNo, TaxMonth, TaxYear in the table the average always returns whatever the "Payments" value is.  If i sum/average both taxMonth and TaxYear then it works, but the data is meaningless without both those columns set to "Dont summarise"

```
3MonthAverage = 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('SQL_MonthlyData'[Payments]),
            DATEADD('SQL_MonthlyData'[FullDate].[Date], -3, MONTH)
        )
```

Expected results

```
CompanyNo TaxMonth TaxYear Payments 3MonthAvg  
1         1        2018    100      100  
1         2        2018    200      150            
1         3        2018    300      200  
1         4        2018    400      300   
2         1        2018    100      100  
2         2        2018    500      300  
2         3        2018    1000     533.33
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:  Add a column like:

```
3MonthAvg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Sheet1[ Payments]);FILTER(Sheet1;Sheet1[CompanyNo] = EARLIER(Sheet1[CompanyNo]) && Sheet1[ TaxMonth]<=EARLIER(Sheet1[ TaxMonth]) && Sheet1[ TaxMonth] + 3 > EARLIER(Sheet1[ TaxMonth])))
```

This trick is in the EARLIER that checks if there are other rows confirming to the criteria: same company and an earler month but max 3.

Note: This will not work when you have more years. I advice you to create dates from the month/year columns and use the same as above.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  Apologies its taken so long to come back, its been a fairly hectic week with the run up to year end so power BI has taken a back seat on the priorities.